# How to edit an event trigged by an anchor from inside of a $.get() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a script that, when you click on an anchor, a $.get function will get the anchor's href and then the href will be removed, but I cannot edit anything about the anchor from inside de get element. Example:

```
// make anchor disappear for example (doesn't work)
$('.belovedanchor').click(function(e) {
  $.get($(this).attr('href')).done(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});

// make an anchor disappear using a function (doesn't work too)
$('.belovedanchor').click(function(e) {
  function do() { $(this).hide(); };
  $.get($(this).attr('href')).done(function() {
    do();
  });
});
```

I don't understand why $(this) change to work with the $.get function istead of the .click event.

How would you guys do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What does "I cannot edit anything about the anchor from inside de get element" mean?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I'm trying just to modify whatever thing from the anchor. For example, on the code example I'm trying to hide de anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems. **Edit:** Only one problem -- I now see from your comment below that `belovedanchor` is not the actual selector in your code.

First, your jQuery selector for the click event handler is most likely incorrect. Change `$('belovedanchor')` to `$('.belovedanchor')` or `$('#belovedanchor')` depending if the anchor is identifiable by either class or element ID respectively.

Second, `this` in the `do` callback function does not refer to the anchor. In JavaScript, scope is set at the function level, so anytime you declare a new function, `this` will refer to that new scope.

Do this instead:

```
$('belovedanchor').click(function(e) {
  var anchor = $(this);
  function do() { anchor.hide(); };
  $.get($(this).attr('href')).done(function() {
    do();
  });
});
```

Simplified:

```
$('belovedanchor').click(function(e) {
  var anchor = $(this);
  $.get(anchor.attr('href')).done(function() {
    anchor.hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work properly

```
$('.belovedanchor').click(function() {
  var selectedancor = $(this);
  var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(myurl, function() {
     selectedanchor.hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: It's an example, in my real script I have a real selector.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work either. `this` in the `$.get` callback function is in a different scope -- it does not refer to the original anchor element in the click handler.

Comment: try this one I have improve my answer